# How to concatenate std::is_same in a struct

Tags: c++, templates

My `enable_if` statement was getting very long so I wanted to somehow typedef. I am not sure what the best way is though.

I tried this, but it doesn't work

```
template<typename T>
struct isValidImageFormat
{
    typedef 
        typename std::is_same<T, float>::value || 
        typename std::is_same<T, unsigned char>::value 
        value;
};
```

The error is:

> expected unqualified-id before »||« token
>                    typename std::is_same::value ||

**Questions:**

- What is wrong with my code?
- What would be a good solution to my Problem?

Comment: `std::is_same<T, float>::value` is not a type, so your whole `typedef` and `typename` business makes no sense to begin with.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want [`std::disjunction`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/disjunction) (the fancy word in philosophy for "or"):

```
typedef std::disjunction<
    std::is_same<T, float>, 
    std::is_same<T, unsigned char>> condition;
```

Then you can use `condition::value` to get a true or false value.  Or if you only want a value, try this:

```
constexpr bool condition =
    std::is_same<T, float>::value || 
    std::is_same<T, unsigned char>::value;
```

Comment: I would mention that `std:: disjunction` is part of C++17. It could be not a viable solution for the OP.

Answer (score 5):

The `typename` keyword is used when you want to work with types, in your example you want to work with `constexpr bool` value.

```
template<typename T>
struct isValidImageFormat
{
    constexpr static bool value =  
       std::is_same<T, float>::value || 
       std::is_same<T, unsigned char>::value;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Using this method, the result of `isValidImageFormat<T>` is always either a `std::true_type` or a `std::false_type`:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct isValidImageFormatImpl
{
    static constexpr bool match = std::is_same<T, float>::value
    or std::is_same<T, unsigned char>::value;

    using type = std::conditional_t<match, std::true_type, std::false_type>;
};


template<typename T>
using isValidImageFormat = typename isValidImageFormatImpl<T>::type;

int main()
{
    std::cout << isValidImageFormat<float>() << '\n';
    std::cout << isValidImageFormat<int>() << '\n';

    static_assert(std::is_same<isValidImageFormat<float>, std::true_type>(), "");
    static_assert(std::is_same<isValidImageFormat<int>, std::false_type>(), "");

}
```

Expected output:

```
1
0
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a struct actually. Since C++14, you can easily use a variable template:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename...>
constexpr bool isValidImageFormatVar = false;

template<typename T, typename U, typename... O>
constexpr bool isValidImageFormatVar<T, U, O...> = std::is_same<T, U>::value || isValidImageFormatVar<T, O...>;

template<typename T>
constexpr bool isValidImageFormat = isValidImageFormatVar<T, float, unsigned char>;

int main() {
    static_assert(isValidImageFormat<float>, "!");
    static_assert(isValidImageFormat<unsigned char>, "!");
    static_assert(not isValidImageFormat<int>, "!");
}
```